# How wide is the default `<body>` margin?

Tags: html, css, margin

What’s the default `margin` that HTML sets for its `<body>` tag? I noticed that there’s some automatic margin, but I’m wondering if anyone knows how much it is (and whether it’s in `px` or `%`, etc.).

Comment: It will vary between browsers.  Consider using normalize http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Comment: Link has changed to https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In most major browsers, the default margin is `8px` on all sides. It is defined in pixels by the `user-agent-stylesheet` your browser provides.

Some browsers allow you to create and use your own `user-agent-stylesheet`, but if you are developing a website, I would recommend staying away from changing this, since your users most likely will not have a modified stylesheet and would then see a different page than you do.

If you want to change it, you can just do this:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  ...
}
```

But if you have a large project and want to be more complete, use [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). It resets a lot of default values to be consistent across browsers.

Comment: Don't need the px

Comment: you also don't need to reset the padding.

Answer (score 7):

According to [W3School's CSS reference,](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)
the default properties and values for a body tag are,

```
body{ display : block; margin : 8px; }
```

And one can quickly get the computed details of any element by accessing the [Computed Pane in the Chrome Dev tools.](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/#examine_and_edit_box_model_parameters)

Answer (score -1):

css default values
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

```
body{ display : block; margin : 8px; }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
* { 
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

> The body can also be reset using the asterix tag.

Comment: along with all other elements that have margins and padding for purposes. You would need to re-add them to all elements. A global reset is not advertised as a "solution" to a minor body margin issue.