# extra space in html

Tags: html, css

i created new simple document with this data

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="header"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;   
}
```

and it view like this :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Nho.jpg)

additional space can seen clearly in image

i fount some solution like use

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

or using

```
.header {
position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

is there any other way to remove this additional space ?

Comment: You asked if there is any other way....  did setting `margin:0` and `padding:0` not work for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML default body margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/html-default-body-margin)

Comment: @Charlie74 both of solution works fine

Comment: @JoshC thankyou for your negative rating ! , i am looking for all way possible like use it in * or position ...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the browser the `body` has a default amount of padding or margin applied to it. To remove it you can simply do:

```
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

Comment: This should work.. but the OP is already using `* {margin:0;padding:0;}`

Comment: @JoshC - my thoughts as well...  it looks like the OP already has this working...  not sure of why the question here.

Comment: The OP asked for another method so I gave him a more specific solution to his problem (that wouldn't affect the margin or padding on unrelated elements)

Answer (score 0):

***Just add this css code***

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: normal;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline:0;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5{
    font-weight: normal;    
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This answer is complete overkill for what the OP was looking for.   Especially since he already was using `* {margin:0; padding:0}`.   There is no need for a complete CSS reset here, especially without some explanation to the OP as to what you were doing here, and why so much code is needed for something already done with one line of coding.