# Unwanted space on left side of header

Tags: html, css

I have a spacing on the left side of my header that I am having troubles getting rid of. If anyone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it. Here is my html and css below.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <Header>
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">about me</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </Header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    width: 100%;
}

header{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 77px;
    background: #cccccc;
}

#logo{
    float: left;
}

nav{
    float: left;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Add `margin:0;` to your `body` CSS too.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason why that is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/html-default-body-margin

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a margin:0 to my body in css.