# CSS: How to remove the space around?

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the empty space above and at the left of the "welcome" box?

```css
#.page{
 background-color: #920000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.heading{
 background-color: #666666;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}
h1{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
  <link rel= "stylesheet" href = "style.css" />
 </head>
 <body background-color = #920000;>
  <div class = "heading">
   <h1>"welcome"</h1>
  </div>
 </body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li>Home</>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</html>
```

Thank You.

Regards,
Micky.

Comment: In short: `body, ul { margin: 0; }`.

Comment: why you write `<nav> `menu outside body ?

Comment: This selector `#.page` is probably not valid...either `#page` or `.page`...one or the other. You HTML structure is invalid too, as commented above.

Comment: @HashemQolami: around _Welcome_ is no `UL`. If so, any browsers use to indentation of lists left padding instead of margin.

Comment: @panther If you look through the code carefully, there's an `<ul>` element within the `<nav>` causing margin collapsing because of the default margin at the top and bottom of list elements.

Comment: @HashemQolami: I see that, but the OP wanted to remove white space around grey Welcome text. And if you reset (left) margin on `UL`, you should null the left padding too.

Comment: @panther Isn't the `<nav>` *around* the Welcome text? It *does* add a white space under the Welcome text and I'm just pointing it out. Besides, reseting padding of `<ul>` is not the case here. I'm not talking about left/right margins, as I mentioned it before, UAs apply a top/bottom margin to the list elements such as UL, LI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `8px` default `margin` on `body`.

```
body {margin: 0;}
```

Comment: In IE6 & IE7 this is the default margin for body `margin: 15px 10px;`

Comment: @Psioniax: maybe, but IE7 and lower are dead. `margin: 0;` override both, `8px` and `15px 10px` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Set `body`and `html`to `margin:0`and `padding:0`

```css
body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#.page{
 background-color: #920000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.heading{
 background-color: #666666;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}
h1{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
  <link rel= "stylesheet" href = "style.css" />
 </head>
 <body background-color = #920000;>
  <div class = "heading">
   <h1>"welcome"</h1>
  </div>
 </body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li>Home</>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you set `padding: 0;` to `body`, when it's default value?

Comment: @panther - Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/html-default-body-margin

Answer (score 0):

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
#.page{
    background-color: #920000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.heading{
    background-color: #666666;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" href = "style.css" />
    </head>
    <body background-color = #920000;>
        <div class = "heading">
            <h1>"welcome"</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset all `padding` and `margin` just do `*{padding: 0; margin:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove default body margin :

```
body {
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

(Ansewering because I don't have enough reputation to comment previous answer.)

It's indeed body default browser *padding*.

Note that you can avoid some or every default browser behaviours by using some CSS-reset sheets.

I personnally love [Normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) as a good reset base. [Others exist](http://cssreset.com/).

The general goal behind CSS resets is to make sure every browser custom rule won't break your design depending on the browser your user use.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

#.page is wrong selector also i did not get you why are you placing nav outside the body? and also i'm getting porper output as you want without changing your code.

```
#.page{
  background-color: #920000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.heading{
  background-color: #666666;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
h1{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

<body>
    <div class = "heading">
        <h1>"welcome"</h1>
    </div>
</body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```