# Trying to make my header image cover left, top, and right sides in CSS

Tags: html, css

How I can remove the edges, or enhance my header image to cover the left, top and right.

Project link on CodePen: http://codepen.io/ArizonaWarriorOne/pen/mJjBQM

```css
.masthead-heading,
.masthead-intro {
  text-align: center;
}
.masthead {
  padding: 10em 0;
}
.masthead-intro {
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
}
.masthead-heading {
  margin-top: 1.2em;
}
.masthead {
  background-image: url('http://jmdarter.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Sonoran-Sunset-Flare.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  border-top: 2em solid #FF6600;
  background-position: center;
 }
```

```html
<header class="masthead">
  <p class="masthead-intro">Hi, I'm</p>
  <h1 class="masthead-heading">Tim</h1>
    
  </header>
<section>
</section>
<section>
</section>
<section>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: The link did not come through

Comment: http://codepen.io/ArizonaWarriorOne/pen/mJjBQM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body element has an [8px margin around it by default in most browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/html-default-body-margin), so extra white space will appear around your page.

Add the following CSS rule to your codepen to get rid of the extra space that the body element has by default:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/maxlaumeister/pen/jPpYKm

Full code:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.masthead-heading,
.masthead-intro {
  text-align: center;
}
.masthead {
  padding: 10em 0;
}
.masthead-intro {
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
}
.masthead-heading {
  margin-top: 1.2em;
}
.masthead {
  background-image: url('http://jmdarter.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Sonoran-Sunset-Flare.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  border-top: 2em solid #FF6600;
  background-position: center;
 }
```

```html
<header class="masthead">
  <p class="masthead-intro">Hi, I'm</p>
  <h1 class="masthead-heading">Tim</h1>
    
  </header>
<section>
</section>
<section>
</section>
<section>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```