# difference between percentage width for relative and fixed

Tags: html, css

i have a page where i have two div elements with different relative and fixed positioning.

```
<div class="outer1">
</div>
<div class="outer2">
</div>
```

and css is

```
 .outer1{
    width:50%;
    height:500px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    }

    .outer2{
    width:50%;
    background:blue;
    height:200px;
    position:fixed;
    }
```

But the problem is that the actual width of both the div elements is different.
i have given width as 50% to both element then why there is difference in width.please help.

Comment: you need this one:https://jsfiddle.net/t5qxs4b7/

Comment: used css reset or html,body{margin:0; padding:0;} Example check to this demo https://jsfiddle.net/t5qxs4b7/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your div `.outer1` is taking `width: 50%` of its parent i.e. `body`. 
Whereas you div `.outer2` is positioned `fixed` and therefore is removed form [normal document flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and will position itself with respect to viewport.

Since every browser applies default 'user agent' stylesheet which includes default margin, paddings for elements therefore width of your document differs from that of viewport, that's why there is slight difference in the widths.

You can reset default browser styles, to get the desired result.

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `Position:fixed` the the `div` takes whole container (i.e. body) as a reference.

A fixed position element is positioned relative to the `viewport`, or the browser window itself.

In this case width of your screen is taken.Including the Extra default Margin of Body.

And When you set Relative to any Element it means  "relative to itself".
The element doesn't care about any rules.

That's why You are getting `.outer` div extra long.Because it is not following the rules of Body tag.

When You use `margin:0` then you can see the effect both are same.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c7dy7b4z/)

Answer (score 2):

use css like this

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
.outer1{
    width:50%;
    height:500px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    }
.outer2{
    width:50%;
    background:blue;
    height:200px;
    position:fixed;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**[what-is-a-css-reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)**

**Used css** **[reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)** or define your `html, body` `margin:0;padding:0;`

**Demo**

```css
html, body
    {
     margin:0; 
      padding:0;
    } 
    .outer1{
        width:50%;
        height:500px;
        background:red;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        }

        .outer2{
        width:50%;
        background:blue;
        height:200px;
        position:fixed;

        }
```

```html
<div class="outer1"></div>
<div class="outer2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated by your the comments, this can be resolved by using a css **[reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)** or **[normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)** or by simply resetting the body [properties yourself](https://jsfiddle.net/akuc72p7/).

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The **reason** this happened is because by default most browser have some `margin` [applied to them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/html-default-body-margin).

As we know, `position: fixed` is [not within the document flow](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and therefore is not affected by the `margin` of the `body` element.

So, really [what you were seeing](https://jsfiddle.net/akuc72p7/1/) was *actually* correct. The element with `position: fixed` was `50%` of the entire viewport, whilst the element with `position: relative` was `50%` of the `body` element minus it's `margin` (which resulted in it being *less wide*).

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
    body
    {
     margin:0; 
      padding:0;
    } 
    .outer1{
        width:50%;
        height:500px;
        background:red;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        }

        .outer2{
        width:50%;
        background:blue;
        height:200px;
        position:fixed;

        }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/t5qxs4b7/4/)