# Why doesn't HTML body background-color obey margin?

Tags: html, css, margin, document-body

According to w3, the **margin** of an element is transparent:

[image: Box-Model Diagram]

I've built a very basic HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

In Chrome, the inspector reports that "body" has an 8px margin:

[image: Picture of Chrome Inspector showing 8px margin]

But on the page, the margin is full of the background color! (Notice that there's no space between my bookmarks bar and the red background - I promise I haven't scrolled.

[image: Picture showing no margin at all]

What's up with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML default body margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/html-default-body-margin)

Comment: @Ranveer not a doublicate

Comment: @Ranveer That seems tangentially related at best, and not at all a duplicate.

Comment: Whoops, sorry for flagging it that way, I didn't know that this wasn't a part of w3 convention. It is so usual that I assumed it to be that way :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background) special cases it.

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the
>   canvas and covers the entire canvas, anchored (for
>   'background-position') at the same point as it would be if it was
>   painted only for the root element itself. The root element does not
>   paint this background again.
>
> For HTML documents, however, we recommend that authors specify the
>   background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element. For
>   documents whose root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML
>   "html" element that has computed values of 'transparent' for
>   'background-color' and 'none' for 'background-image', user agents must
>   instead use the computed value of the background properties from that
>   element's first HTML "BODY" element or XHTML "body" element child when
>   painting backgrounds for the canvas, and must not paint a background
>   for that child element. Such backgrounds must also be anchored at the
>   same point as they would be if they were painted only for the root
>   element.

… presumably because people were too used to `<body background="#ff0000">` from the bad old days.

Comment: I think they had to add the special case for compatability to older HTML-Projects, that had no margin, and then would have looked diffrent