# Remove left padding css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple fixed navigation bar, but there is a white margin/padding down the left of the computer screen that I can't figure out how to get rid of.

CSS:

```css
#menu-bar {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 110px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #333;
}
#menu-bar a {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu-bar a:hover {
  color: grey;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="menu-bar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please add a working sample, it would help us to see what's happening..

Comment: add `left:0px;` to `#menu-bar`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In most major browsers, the default margin is 8px on all sides. It is
>   defined in pixels by the user-agent-stylesheet your browser provides.
>
> Some browsers allow you to create and use your own
>   user-agent-stylesheet, but if you are developing a website, I would
>   recommend staying away from changing this, since your users most
>   likely will not have a modified stylesheet and would then see a
>   different page than you do.

So, You can **Reset/Normalize** your css by adding this code:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

But if you have a large project and want complete restting use [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/). It resets a lot of default values to be consistent across browsers. Good Luck ^_^!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the default margin on the `<body>` element:

```css
#menu-bar {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 110px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #333;
}
#menu-bar a {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu-bar a:hover {
  color: grey;
}
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-bar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see why you need to remove default margin as it's `fixed` positioning

Comment: @Pogrindis - Since there's no left position specified on the fixed element, the body's default margin will still effect the layout.

Comment: agreed, but I would just be more inclined to apply a `left:0;` instead of manipulating a parent, the padding on the body is somewhat expected.

Comment: @Pogrindis However by only changing the left position of the menu bar, the rest of the page will still be affected by the body's margin, which would then make everything out of alignment. Your suggestion is valid, but it also depends on the rest of the OP's layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin: 0;` to the body to remove its default margin style.  Example below:

```css
body{
   margin:0;
}
#menu-bar {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 110px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #333;
}
#menu-bar a {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu-bar a:hover {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-bar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely default margin on the body. You can set this to 0 with the following:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/html-default-body-margin) for more information