# why is there margin/padding on the left side of my text

Tags: html, css, text, padding, margin

I am styling a newsletter for different mail clients but i have one problem and that is that the copyright text on the bottom seems to be adding padding or margin on the left side of it and i can not figure out why. I have tried many things like putting the padding left and margin left on 0 but that does not seem to work. Does anyone have a fix for this problem ?.

Comment: There's not a lot we can help you with without some example code. Could you show us what you tried? Also: email templates are... wel.. not too giving with HTML. A lot of businesses use <table>s in <table>s (in <table>s.. etc.) to get the exact layout they want.

Comment: Use an email framework [like mjlm](https://mjml.io) for creating html mails. Other then that, all we can say for now is: You have an error in your code, fix it. Can't say what specifically wihtout any code posted.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this yet?

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

link: [Removing body margin in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208335/removing-body-margin-in-css)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment and yes i have tried it but it has no effect.

Comment: did you add
body{
   margin:0;
}

although otherwise you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483881/remove-left-padding-css

Comment: I have already fixed this issue thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `<ul>` tag? It has a CSS Default Values `padding-inline-start: 40px;`.

You can remove it by setting it to 0px,i.e. `padding-inline-start: 0;`