# HTML How do I make sure the header of my page is covered completely?

Tags: html

My header does not fully covers my page making the background color overlaps them both together.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#header {
    background-color: black;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: blue;">

        <div id="header">
    <p>hi</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because browsers have a default margin / padding.
//edit [HTML default body margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/html-default-body-margin)

Add this to your css

```
html,body{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
p{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: missing <p> margin

Comment: @Tommy woops, ty added

Comment: Thanks for the support!! been trying to figure this out for hours

Answer (score 1):

You need to set both html and body height, then #header height, like so

```css
html, body, #header {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  background-color: blue;
}

p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<p>
Hi!
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you inspect the html and check the CSS applied to `body` tag, you will see that it has a default `margin: 8px`. You will have to make it 0.

Use `margin: 0px` to set the new margin to `body` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox (for example) indicates that there is a "border" of 8. Adding `border: 0` to body's style made the thin blue borders to the left and right disappear. Is that what you wanted?