# Having problems with aligning layers with body background

Tags: html, css, background, position, parallax

I'm creating a layered parallax page that is triggered by the scrolling of the mouse. I've managed to set this up and the layers all move how I want them to. Unfortunately, I've run into a problem with the background image of the body. On the left side of the screen, there is a gap that shows the background behind it.

Gap that shows the background:
[image: Gap that shows the background]

I've tried many different solutions but none of them seems to work. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

here's the snippet of my HTML that involves the section with the layers

```html
<section>
        <img src="./Images/stars.png" id="stars">
        <img src="./Images/moon.png" id="moon">
        <img src="./Images/mountains_behind.png" id="mountains_behind">
        <h2 id="text">Moon Light</h2>
        <img src="./Images/mountains_front.png" id="mountains_front">
    </section>
```

and here's a snippet of the CSS

```css
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sixing: border-box;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;

    }

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(#2b1055,#7597de);
}

section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 100px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

section img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    pointer-events: none;

}
```

Comment: Your first css block is missing its selector.

Comment: Add `margin: 0; padding: 0` to the body selector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How wide is the default \`<body>\` margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/how-wide-is-the-default-body-margin)

Comment: The property `box-sizing:` has a small type-o 'box-*sixing*:' as well. This might be one issue (*not the most striking one such as the selector missing*), due to the box-sizing defaulting to `border-box: content-box;` which adds the borders on the outside instead of the intended inside.

Comment: @andiOak  thank you for your help- fixed the problem instantly :)

Comment: @FabianSchöner Hi this helped, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would structure the first two selectors like this:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* put these last two in a 'html {}' only selector if they are intended to be different */
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(#2b1055,#7597de);
}
```

Btw, changed the type-o of box-*sixing* to the [right property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) :). Never used that one before, will come very handy, thanks.