# HTML still has gaps in container despite 0 margin/padding

Tags: html, css

So all I have is a single line of text with a background color in red. Margin and padding are set to 0. Theres no children causing indentures as far as I know but I still get a gap all around my container.

My CSS

```
{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px; 
    

    background-color: rgb(207, 30, 30);
   
}
```

My HTML

```
<div class="main-container">
TEST
</div>
```

My Result
[image]

Please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with something so simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapped entire element would be body? Then you have apply padding and margin 0 to it. You can write in your Style:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

That will be remove this space.

Answer (score 0):

The `body` element actually [has a default margin of 8px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/how-wide-is-the-default-body-margin). So setting it to 0 should fix the problem.

```
body { margin: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers tend to have default settings for elements - especially margin - so depending on  your browser there may be settings for parent elements' margins - if nothing else maybe html and body so a setting of

- {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

is quite often seen at the top of stylesheets to remove these defaults.