# Table won't go 100% wide

Tags: html

I'm trying to make the table wide from border to boarder but it didn't went as expected. Bellow is an example

```
<table  style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="$bordercolor">
&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want the table to start excatly from the boarder of the page but there is still a little space, the white space, before it begins. You know why? [Attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osg7G.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How wide is the default \`<body>\` margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/how-wide-is-the-default-body-margin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest trying the below;

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/x1tvohas/