# gap around main container in react

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

i am using the styled component to wrap my complete code but due to some reason my container component leaves gap around it and does not expand to full screen

[image]

[image]

[image]

tried giving it a negative margin but that did not work and nither the full screen media query

Comment: have you reset the margin of body tag itself?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/how-wide-is-the-default-body-margin